# How to npm publish all files in the root folder

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, package.json

I have this `package.json`

```
 {
  "name": "snabbpixi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "snabbpixi.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.4",
    "testiz": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "pixi.js": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```

I have these files in the root folder

`snabbpixi.js`, `vnode.js`

When I publish this project using `yarn publish` and install using `yarn install` and I look in the `node_modules` folder, I see the `vnode.js` file is not published. How can I publish this file in the root directory to npm?

Comment: `yarn publish` publishes your package to the npm registry. That is, you've put your package online. `yarn install` installs all the devDeps and deps for your project. `node_modules` is a directory reserved for the dependencies of your project. Your project files won't (shouldn't) go in there.

Comment: Both files are published under the [`src` directory](https://unpkg.com/snabbpixi@1.0.1/src/), though only `snabbpixi.js` is in your [root directory](https://unpkg.com/snabbpixi@1.0.1/) because `@babel/preset-env` bundles your output into a single file with the same name as the entry point.

Comment: @PranavA. I think you misunderstand. They're checking the `node_modules` where `snabbpixi` installed to, not under _its_ dependencies.

Comment: But I have the `vnode.js` file in the root folder, it is generated by `yarn run compile` @PatricRoberts

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was I had a `.gitignore` file, with `vnode.js` defined, that made `npm` ignore the file.

I added an additional `.npmignore` file and it published fine.